# How can I get the dev name associated to a Volume name?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

I am creating a bash script to unmount my usb drive after the backup is done.
To unmount the drive I use the command:

```
diskutil unmount disk4s1
```

But sometimes when I plug my usb drive it gets a different dev name, as disk3s1, or disk2s1.
I need add a line in my script before unmount the disk, to get the dev name associated to my volume name.

What command could I use to get the dev name given its volume name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mount | grep /Volumes/foo | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

or

```
mount | awk '/Volumes\/foo/ { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Thank you!. This is my bash code to unmount myvolume working perfect now : 

devname=$(mount | grep /Volumes/myvolume | cut -d ' ' -f1);

osascript -e 'do shell script "diskutil unmount '$devname'" '

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the volume name with diskutil though, there's no need to get the identifier:

```
$ diskutil unmount VolumeName
Volume VolumeName on disk1s1 unmounted
```